# I not Getting Proper TreeView while using js tree in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my json Data

```
[{"id":"1","name":"#","text":"Root"},{"id":"2","name":"#","text":"Menu"},{"id":"3","name":"2","text":"File1"},{"id":"4","name":"1","text":"Folder1"}]
```

and I am Getting Tree like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z7T3.png)

Whats the Problem I dont  no,I hv tried everythig but not getting proper answer

Answer (score 1):

Below is a demo about how to use  js tree in asp.net core. You can refer to it.

VehicleType:

```
public class VehicleType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

VehicleSubType:

```
public class VehicleSubType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

TreeViewNode:

```
public class TreeViewNode
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private DBCtx Context { get; }
    public HomeController(DBCtx _context)
    {
        this.Context = _context;
    }
 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<TreeViewNode> nodes = new List<TreeViewNode>();
 
        //Loop and add the Parent Nodes.
        foreach (VehicleType type in this.Context.VehicleTypes)
        {
            nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode { id = type.Id.ToString(), parent = "#", text = type.Name });
        }
 
        //Loop and add the Child Nodes.
        foreach (VehicleSubType subType in this.Context.VehicleSubTypes)
        {
            nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode { id = subType.VehicleTypeId.ToString() + "-" + subType.Id.ToString(), parent = subType.VehicleTypeId.ToString(), text = subType.Name });
        }
 
        //Serialize to JSON string.
        ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes);
        return View();
    }
 
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string selectedItems)
    {
        List<TreeViewNode> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TreeViewNode>>(selectedItems);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Index view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jstree">
    </div>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <input type="hidden" name="selectedItems" id="selectedItems"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var i, j;
                var selectedItems = [];
                for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
 
                    //Fetch the Id.
                    var id = data.selected[i];
 
                    //Remove the ParentId.
                    if(id.indexOf('-') != -1){
                        id = id.split("-")[1];
                    }
 
                    //Add the Node to the JSON Array.
                    selectedItems.push({
                        text: data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text,
                        id: id,
                        parent: data.node.parents[0]
                    });
                }
 
                //Serialize the JSON Array and save in HiddenField.
                $('#selectedItems').val(JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
            }).jstree({
                "core": {
                    "themes": {
                        "variant": "large"
                    },
                    "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json)
                    },
                "checkbox": {
                    "keep_selected_style": false
                },
                "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: me to got the tree but next step is to attach context menu and perform actions for create ,delete and rename using popup modal and every changes has to store in databse